# Field Name "_LikeCount and _CommentCount" is not recognize in Graph Explorer

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

Hi I'am trying to query most liked and commented news in SharePoint SitePages however when trying to order descending using _LikeCount and _CommentCount i received this error:

> A provided field name is not recognized

. I dont have any issue with other fields except these two.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{ID}/lists/Site Pages/items?$filter=fields/PromotedState eq 2&expand=fields($select=createdDateTime,BannerImageUrl,PromotedState,FileLeafRef,AuthorLookupId,Modified,_CommentCount,_LikeCount,Title,Description,LinkTitle)&$top=5&$orderby=fields/_LikeCount desc
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `PromotedState` field name is not recognized as a valid field name and also `$orderby` clause does not support ordering by field `_LikeCount`.

Try run the query without `$filter` and `$orderby` to check what fields are returned

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{ID}/lists/Site Pages/items?$expand=fields($select=createdDateTime,BannerImageUrl,PromotedState,FileLeafRef,AuthorLookupId,Modified,_CommentCount,_LikeCount,Title,Description,LinkTitle)&$top=5
```

Run the query with the `$orderby`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{ID}/lists/Site Pages/items?$expand=fields($select=createdDateTime,BannerImageUrl,PromotedState,FileLeafRef,AuthorLookupId,Modified,_CommentCount,_LikeCount,Title,Description,LinkTitle)&$top=5&$orderby=fields/_LikeCount desc
```

It will return `invalidRequest` error.

Run the query with the `$filter`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{ID}/lists/Site Pages/items?$expand=fields($select=createdDateTime,BannerImageUrl,PromotedState,FileLeafRef,AuthorLookupId,Modified,_CommentCount,_LikeCount,Title,Description,LinkTitle)&$filter=fields/PromotedState eq 2&$top=5
```

It will return `invalidRequest` error.

Comment: PromotedState works with $orderby and $filter. However _LikeCount and _CommentCount doesnt and returning  "ror": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "A provided field name is not recognized"," any idea how to make this work? thanks!

Comment: @BizApps Is it possible to order the result on the client?

Comment: the issue if we dot it in client is that the source of site pages may contain thousands of pages so it will be slow if we do it in client side.